# Python Dictionary JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am making a get request as shown below:

```
testHeaders = {'X-Api-Key':'myAPIKey'}
testURL = 'https://api.mytest.com/v2/test.json'
r = requests.get(testURL, headers=testHeaders)
status =  r.status_code
response = r.json()
```

My response returns a dictionary object with two keys and then multiple values inside each key.

How can I assign each of these keys and then access and assess the data inside?

I've looked online and can't seem to find anything relevant.

Example of JSON structure

`[{"id":000001,"account":000001,"name":"testName1","host":testHost1","test_color":"green"}`

I have multiple records like the above

Comment: What do you want exactly? To extract keys as variables, or just to peak inside and take some of the values corresponding to keys? Or do want just to examine the structure of said JSON? You can manipulate JSON just as any dictionary in python.

Comment: I get two keys (test1,test2), I then want to peak inside the data inside say test1 and look for matching values, lets say I want to return data that matches 'testValue':'green'

Comment: This is basic dictionary manipulation, which is covered in any introductory tutorial. For example: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. If you've tried something and had a specific issue, give a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I have been a little unclear on my post, I have looked at the documentation and this is where I am confused. The problem here is that one of my keys has around 700 records which appear to be tuples containing multiple values. I want to assess one of those values and then return that record.

Comment: Can you post small sample of your JSON so we could better see it's structure and what are you trying to grab from it?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: @a_m_2016 I have edited my answer, does that approach help?

Comment: I don't believe, so I will do some further research.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you have a `test1` key, you can search for `green` like (assuming that your json has two keys (test1 and test2) with nested values):

```
for key, value in response.items():
    # key will return key  test1 and test2
    # value will return a tuple 'testValue':'green'
    if key == 'test1':
        if 'test_color' in value:
            color = value[test_color]
```